# Largest common prefix of two strings in CMake

Tags: cmake

I need to find the largest common prefix of two strings using CMake. I did not yet find anything about it using CMake. CMake itself is quite limited so I wonder about the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the largest common prefix is usually done in an O(n) linear search beginning at the start of both strings. CMake allows comparing numbers and strings using the [if command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) and LESS/GREATER/.. . This allows to implement the standard way of finding the largest common prefix:

```
function( largest_common_prefix a b prefix )

# minimum of lengths of both strings
string( LENGTH ${a} len_a )
string( LENGTH ${b} len_b )

if( ${len_a} LESS ${len_b} )
    set( len ${len_a} )
else()
    set( len ${len_b} )
endif()

# iterate over the length
foreach( end RANGE 1 ${len} )
    # get substrings
    string( SUBSTRING ${a} 0 ${end} sub_a )
    string( SUBSTRING ${b} 0 ${end} sub_b )
    
    # if equal store, otherwise break
    if ( ${sub_a} STREQUAL ${sub_b} )
        set( ${prefix} ${sub_a} PARENT_SCOPE )
    else()
        break()
    endif()
endforeach()

endfunction()
```

Comment: `string( LENGTH ${a} len_b )` -> `string( LENGTH ${b} len_b )`